# google mlkit faceDetector in startImageStream broken - Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, google-mlkit

I new in flutter and I want to count the frequency of blinks in the user's eyes.
I use startImageStream to get the image and mlkit.
this is my code:

```
await cameraController.startImageStream((CameraImage img) =>
  _proccessImageToBlinking(img));

 void _proccessImageToBlinking(CameraImage img) async {
int numOfEyesBlink = 0;
VisionFaceDetectorOptions options = new VisionFaceDetectorOptions(
    modeType: VisionFaceDetectorMode.Accurate,
    landmarkType: VisionFaceDetectorLandmark.None,
    classificationType: VisionFaceDetectorClassification.All,
    minFaceSize: 0.1,
    isTrackingEnabled: true);
FirebaseVisionFaceDetector faceDetector = FirebaseVisionFaceDetector
    .instance;
var imgByte = img.planes.map((plane) {return plane.bytes;}).toList().first;
List<VisionFace> face = await faceDetector.detectFromBinary(imgByte, options);
if (!face[0].hasLeftEyeOpenProbability &&
    !face[0].hasRightEyeOpenProbability) {
  numOfEyesBlink++;
  print("blinking");
}
```

}

The code is broken in this line:

```
List<VisionFace> face = await faceDetector.detectFromBinary(imgByte, options);
```

in services\binding in line ByteData? response;
I think it has to do with the way the imgByte comes, but I could not understand why.
I also get this line all the time in consola -

```
Background concurrent copying GC freed 2456(184KB) AllocSpace objects, 69(4676KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 5132KB/10MB, paused 4.580ms total 185.865ms
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you know the image format that `detectFromBinary` supports? Your `imgByte` must be wrong.